# Write base64 btoa to file using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am reeving a large base64 that looks something like this in my Nodejs server. This was sent by converting a PDF to base64 from my front end

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA1....
```

Is there a way to save to base64 as a file now using Nodejs?

Comment: [base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64)

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the dataurl back into a PDF and save it to a file?

Comment: Yes. Covert and save

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a data URL in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335460/how-do-i-parse-a-data-url-in-node)

Comment: Sure, decode it at save--what's the specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to decode the base64 string as binary

```
var bin = Base64.atob(stringToDecode);
// Your code to handle binary data
fs.writeFile('result_binary.pdf', bin, 'binary', error => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log('binary saved!');
    }
});
```

referece:
[Decoding Base64 pdf giving broken file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483097/decoding-base64-pdf-giving-broken-file)